# Android Studio debugger listing variables like IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, code-inspection

using Android Studio for development. Last week I discovered really neat feature in IntelliJ IDEA IDE, which when debugging Java app shows listing of variables next to the line of code. It is really helpful.

I have been wondering if the same option can be enabled in AS, since it uses the same core? Anybody knows? I would really love to use it in AS as well.

Here is screenshot what I am talking about.:
[image: debugger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Studio 1.2 Preview 1](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio12preview1) has been released just this week, and is the first version of Android Studio based on IntelliJ 14.

Since the feature you're describing was introduced in IntelliJ 14, Android Studio 1.2 will contain this feature as well:

[image]

Please note that this is an alpha release, so expect to encounter bugs.

Comment: Thank you guys very much all. I have downloaded 1.2 preview and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's a new feature of IntelliJ IDEA 14, as you can see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#debugger_tab).

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA 13, so currently it is not possible to have such feature. Anyway if you want to have it you can always download IntelliJ IDEA 14 and use the Android plugin, which covers the same funcionality that Android Studio does:

From Jetbrains [FAQ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/):

> **When can I get the Android Studio features in IntelliJ IDEA?**
>
> The EAP of IntelliJ IDEA 13, which includes all of the Android Studio
>   features except for the redesigned new project wizard and the App
>   Engine cloud endpoints integration, is available now. The remaining
>   features are going to be integrated in the coming weeks.
>
> - See more at: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/#sthash.OPJSeIA2.dpuf

To Download this plugin in IDEA 14, go to Settings, Plugins and then Search for Android Support:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Preview has recently been [updated](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio12preview1) to use IntelliJ IDEA 14. If you want to get the new updated make sure you are set to receive updates from the Cannery channel.

To do this go to `Android Studio > Check for updates...`

[image]

Then Click the `Updates` text and select the channel you wish to receive updates from.